# IE error "Url Too Long" isn't returned

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, iis-6

I've been trying to identify a problem with an Ajax function that's sending large amounts of text to an ASP page. I believe the problem to be that when lots of text is entered into a form/input and the data is sent via Ajax, this results in a very large 'querystring'.

The server returns the error "Url Too Long". However, I have tested this application on two different computers - both running IE8 - and on one of them, executing the same request returns nothing at all. So my question is, does anyone know how this error/feedback could be switched off? I'm guessing it's not a server setting as both computers are accessing the same application. I've tried turning off "Show friendly HTTP error messages" on the suspect computer but this hasn't helped.

Comment: Change from GET to POST: i.e. don't send your request as a query string, POST the data. How are you sending the request now?

Comment: I've tried doing it as POST and it works fine. I was more trying to work out what determines when these errors are returned. Thanks!

Comment: See [What is the maximum length of a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/417142/911083) for general, but as to why one machine allows more than 2083, I think it can be affected by service packs or .NET library versions too. Best to just accept that 2000 is too big and use POST instead :)

Comment: Well I'm actually sending a URL of over 8000 characters as a test. Neither computer will process it, but only one of them returns an actual error message. So it's not really a case of one working and the other not working, but more a case of one of them not telling me why it's not working. Apart from that, I accept and will use POST! :)